# Is this a correct way of calculating productivity? And can the proposed data be (accurately) used for doing so?

Tags: gdp, productivity

I want to know if my thinking for calculating productivity [2019-USD/hour-worked] is correct.

**Basics:**
Take the GDP of a country and divide by the total amount of hours worked in that country -> voilá you get productivity. **Is this correct?**

**Specifics**
I plan to use OECD data for my estimation in the following way:

- The total hours worked I plan to get by taking the hours/worker data (https://data.oecd.org/emp/hours-worked.htm) times the size of the labor force [# workers] data (https://data.oecd.org/emp/hours-worked.htm). This should get me the total amount of hours worked.
- Get the productivity by dividing the PPP adjusted total GDP [PPP adjusted GDP in 2019-USD] by the total amount of hours worked, where I want to use the GDP data from https://data.oecd.org/gdp/gross-domestic-product-gdp.htm

**Questions**

1. Is my thinking correct?
2. Do you think the data I have chosen is appropriate for my use case?

Thanks!

Comment: The OECD does similar calculations in https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=PDB_LV if you select "GDP per hour worked" as the Subject

Comment: Now that is useful! Would it be "correct" to translate those 2015 PPP values into say 2019 PPP values using inflation data? If so, what inflation data would you recommend using. If not, how would you recommend making them into 2019 PPP?

Comment: The USA figure for 2019 in the "2015 PPPs" table is 71.8 while in the "current PPPs" version of that table is 77.0, so a plausible attempt to get to 2019 PPPs might be to multiply every number in the "2015 PPPs" table by 77.0/71.8

Comment: Ah. Basically to just account for inflation of the US dollar?